# can i change the url when i select a menu in the side menu and adding url navigation to go to the same page

Tags: flutter

can I change the URL when I select a menu in the side menu and adding URL navigation to go to the same page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uZl3.png)

I wanted to change the URL on sidebar click and navigate to appropriate screen with Sidebar

Answer (score 0):

you can use package `go_route`

example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

/// This sample app shows an app with two screens.
///
/// The first route '/' is mapped to [HomeScreen], and the second route
/// '/details' is mapped to [DetailsScreen].
///
/// The buttons use context.go() to navigate to each destination. On mobile
/// devices, each destination is deep-linkable and on the web, can be navigated
/// to using the address bar.
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// The route configuration.
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const HomeScreen();
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'details',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const DetailsScreen();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

/// The main app.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [MyApp]
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

/// The home screen
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [HomeScreen]
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/details'),
              child: const Text('Go to the Details screen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The details screen
class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [DetailsScreen]
  const DetailsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Details Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <ElevatedButton>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/'),
              child: const Text('Go back to the Home screen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```